# Better way to associate ticket quantities with event dates?

Tags: entities, datetime

I'm fairly new to events in Drupal 7 but I have at least spent a few days now investigating strategies for my use case. Unfortunately, I haven't found a single relevant piece of info.

I have some recurring events that need to have a remaining tickets number associated with each event date. Some of these events are literally movies in a museum and teachers need to be able to see how many tickets are available for each show time when selecting dates and times for their field trips. Thus, movie show times is a useful (and accurate) model for this issue.

Within a single event node it's simple enough to create multiple date fields and multiple remaining tickets fields for the event. However, I've not been able to figure out how to associate a given remaining tickets number with a specific event date. So far, I only have lists of unrelated dates and numbers.

The alternate "solution" I've come up with is to have an event description node and numerous distinct event date (show time) nodes. The event date (show time) nodes would contain the event date and the tickets remaining for that date. However, I can't think of a way of explicitly connecting the event date nodes to the relevant event description node other than also including the node id in the event date nodes (which, for other reasons, is far from ideal).

Does anyone more experienced with events know whether this explicit connection is even likely to be needed? Even better, can anyone point me in a less cumbersome direction (e.g., associating the tickets required numbers with the right dates, all in one node, instead of creating separate event date nodes)?

Thanks so much for any and all assistance you're able to give!!!
James Baker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue down the road you are on now, having an event description node and separate event date nodes, I would recommend you take a look at the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references).

If you want to keep all information within one node for a given movie/event, perhaps take a look at the [Field Collection module](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection).  The article [Create Multigroups in Drupal 7 using Field Collections](http://oliverdavies.co.uk/blog/create-multigroups-drupal-7-using-field-collections) may assist you to accomplish this.

Comment: Wow! I'm following the article you referenced to use the Field Collection module and it looks like it's going to work for what I need. Thanks so much for your help! I'll set your response as the answer as soon as I've tested everything out.

Comment: Thanks, @Laxman13. I can't get the data entered into Field Collections to display with views. Getting the [Invalid field name given. in FieldCollectionItemEntity->__construct() ...](http://drupal.org/node/1084268) error. A little concerned about applying the patch from [Comment #24](http://drupal.org/node/1084268#comment-4967014) there. I can't tell to which file the patch should be applied or if the patch will be compatible with future module updates. Any thoughts from anyone experienced with this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with the Field Collections module.  Perhaps someone else can chime in

Comment: Cygwin tells me the patch from [#24](http://drupal.org/node/1084268#comment-4967014) was successfully applied but I'm still receiving exactly the same error. Applied patch to both [7.x-1.0-beta2](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) (2011-Aug-18) and [7.x-1.x-dev](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) (2011-Sep-27). Any additional assistance will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I ended up going with the approach of separating event dates from event descriptions and having each event date node contain a reference back to the event description via the References module. Thanks again!